# Cron doesn't run Rails Puma server automatically in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, cron, puma

I deployed a Rails application in Digital Ocean Ubuntu Server using Capistrano. For some reason the puma server suddenly stops. I'm not sure what's the reason.

That's why I created a script **/home/deploy/startup-script.sh**
the script contains the commands to startup the Rails application in daemon

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running Puma Server"
touch hello.txt
cd /srv/www/apps/app/current
bundle exec puma -C /srv/www/apps/app/shared/puma.rb --daemon
```

then I run this script every minute using Cron.
My **crontab -e** contains

```
* * * * * ./startup-script.sh
```

After 1 minute I noticed that it created a hello.txt file but my puma server is not running.
But when I run it manually using `./startup-script.sh` it will run the server.

**puma_error.log**

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.0-p0), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 8
* Environment: production
* Daemonizing...
=== puma startup: 2020-09-21 05:16:28 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2020-09-21 05:17:39 +0000 ===
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
=== puma startup: 2020-09-21 06:11:35 +0000 ===
- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 2020-09-21 06:11:35 +0000 ===
```

**production.log**

```
 Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 208], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Unit Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 215], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Unit Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 198], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Unit Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data Delivery Receipt 12-2020-001.pdf (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4326ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 37.4ms)
```

**puma_access.log**

```
=== puma startup: 2020-12-01 01:07:13 +0000 ===
```

When starting the `startup-script.sh` script I'm getting this

```
Running Puma Server
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.0-p0), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 8
* Environment: production
* Daemonizing...
```

My droplet is still running but the puma running on port 9292 disappears when crashes, so I suspect this is puma error.

Comment: From the comment it seems that Puma might be stopping due to a signal to stop (it received a signal indicating it should exit, which initiated a graceful shutdown)... This could happen due to different reasons. You might need to look at your scripts / code to see if you're sending a `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, limiting memory consumption on a very low limit or indicating that all child processed must exit once the script ends.

Comment: I checked my code and I didn't send any `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`. Are there other ways if I can listen continuously to port 9292 and if it's not running then run my startup-script.sh ?

Comment: You issue really isn't with Puma. I assume this only happens during deployment...? Did you look at the Capistrano logs? I can't see them in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of Puma, the `--daemon` option might be deprecated. Use `&` instead:

```
bundle exec puma -C /srv/www/apps/app/shared/puma.rb &
```

However, your issue isn't with Cron or with Puma. Puma doesn't exit on its own unless something else happens. I recommend that you have a look at the error logs and figure out the real issue.

### Edit:

To answer your comment:

1. I recommend that you update Puma to version the latest 4.x release (currently 4.3.6). If you can switch to Puma 5.x (currently 5.1) that would be even better. There are bug fixes and improvements all the time. Maybe your issue is related to a solved bug.
2. If you update to the 5.x version family, you will need to replace the `--daemon` with a `&` as mentioned above.

**Side Note**:

However, I still believe there's an error report you didn't notice of that your toolset failed to log.

I don't know if you looked at the [Capistrano logs](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/) as well as the Rails / Puma logs and the DigitalOcean server logs.

If you're running Puma with `--debug`, some Puma messages must appear in the log.

Comment: I'm currently using Puma 4.3.1. I checked the logs and I cannot see any errors. My application is running in port 9292. I'm not sure what's the reason for this crash. Any idea I can detect if my port 9292 is down then I run the shell script instead?

Comment: You may not see any errors, but the logs would still improve your question because they allow us to rule out irrelevant issues. In addition, please make sure to post snippets from all the different logs, for the deployment, the app and the server (droplet) startup / shutdown. The the droplet is restarting, it's good to know.

Comment: I added the logs to my question. the puma_error.log shows that it was gracefully shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I don't think puma just stops by itself. Maybe it is not running properly as a daemon? I would suggest to figure out what's going on.

That being said, in order to ensure that a certain daemon is always up and running you should use a tool like supervisord: http://supervisord.org/

A cronjob is not the right tool.

Comment: My application is running in the first place after deploy but after a while my app crashes. I checked my logs (puma_access.log, puma_error.log, production.log) and I cannot see any errors. Is there a way I can run the script if my app crashes. My app is running in port 9292